# Symfony2 creating routes based on language locale

Tags: php, symfony

I'm implementing translator for a multilingual site. It all works fine but when the user tries to change the language, the language stays the same.

This is the route...

```
index:
    path:  /{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: HotelIndexBundle:Index:index , _locale:hr}
    requirements:
        _locale: hr|en
```

In a twig template I have to links that go to this path with...

```
path('index');
```

To lets say that I'm in my index page www.example.com (it defaults to 'hr'). The user then changes to www.example.com/en. It works. But when it tries to get back to hr with path('index'), the page reverts to same www.example.com/en.

There is also a problem with additional url parameters like www.example.com/en/contact. How to change it to www.example.com/hr/contact AND stay on the /contact page?

Comment: Have you tried passing the current _local from controller to your twig file (as e.g. current_locale) and `{{ path("index", {"_locale": current_locale}) }}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **To lets say that I'm in my index page www.example.com (it defaults to**
>   **'hr'). The user then changes to www.example.com/en. It works. But when**
>   **it tries to get back to hr with path('index'), the page reverts to**
>   **same www.example.com/en.**

You should have the following configuration in your config.yml file:

**config.yml**

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

The locale parameter should be defined in parameters.yml file:

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    locale: hr
```

> **There is also a problem with additional url parameters like**
>   **www.example.com/en/contact. How to change it to**
>   **www.example.com/hr/contact AND stay on the /contact page?**

It can be done like this:

```
{% set requestParams = app.request.attributes.get('_route_params') %}
{% set requestRoute = app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}

<a href="{{ path(requestRoute, requestParams|merge({'_locale' : 'en'})) }}">en</a>
<a href="{{ path(requestRoute, requestParams|merge({'_locale' : 'hr'})) }}">hr</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [JMSi18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle). It does exactly what you want.

Comment: So there isn't a built in Symfony function or something else that does that?

Comment: Just wanted to bump up this answer as this is exactly how I did it fewe months ago ;) @MarioLegenda: No, there is not built it way